# Competing private currencies vs a single global currency

Tags: economy, central-bank, money-supply

Recently, I read Friedrich Hayek's book "Denationalisation of Money", in which he suggests ending the central bank's monopoly on the money supply by creating competitive private currencies and allowing the free market to provide the optimal quantity (and variety) of monetary products.

Alternatively, we can consider a scenario that is the opposite of Hayek's: a single global monopoly with one currency and one central bank controlling it.

Are there any good mathematical models that allow us to predict what would happen to the national and global economies if either:

1. The central bank was completely abolished and all money was issued by competing private organizations
2. All money supply in the world was provided by one authority

Comment: Economics is as much science as it is black magic. I'm sure there are all sorts of models out there, but I imagine it'd be hard to say they were anything other than SWAGs

Comment: And how would the entities of 1) back up their money? I am private entity #1, if I do not need to back up my money the best thing I can do is print as much money until the value of the things I can buy with that money is not enough to the cost of physically printing that  money... the not-so-technical name for that situation is **scam**.

Comment: @SJuan76 Mr. Hayek says, that in the market this behaviour will be blocked by the competing money producers. If someone prints too much money, other money will be used. Plus we have an example of bitcoin, where emission is limited by the algorithm.

Comment: Nonsense. It will be too easy to build a reputation as an stable currency and, when that is done, put the printing machines at 100% production. All the benefits for the printing entity, all the disavantages for the society. That's why I call it a scam. And emission limited by external issues like bitcoin is also bad, as it lacks the flexibility of increasing money supply when it is needed.

Comment: @SJuan76 Your argument could be valid in In case of a very big market share of 1 company and it's ability to inflate the amount of money very quickly. But in case, when there are several competing stable currencies, if 1 issuer decides to overprint, it's exchange rate will decline, signalling to the public, that something is wrong with it. This process won't be instant. And eventually the public won't use this money at all and the company will bankrupt. Like Zimbabwe hyperinflation case: Zimbabwe dollar is gone.

Comment: No, the ones hurt would be the ones that accepted that company money's. In fact, this has been done before many times, just that the company was selling "stock" or debt instead of "money". And, guess what? With no external (government) control, time and time again the temptation of printing too much of it has been to strong. These kinds of ideas are drawn on premises like "suppose that the market has perfect information and rational behavior" which are much like "imagine an spherical cow".

Comment: One problem is also that this kind of competition usually goes down to very few important "competitors" or even just one (after all it is unpleasant to exchange money) - and then you'd have a money system ruled by someone who's purpose is money and power, not serving the public. No good. :-(

Comment: @user4035 The exchange rate will decline, the company's money will stop being used ever again, but it will be too late, because the company's owners already exchanged all their newly printed money for other money which is still good. Meanwhile the *ordinary people* who used that company's money are now bankrupt.

Comment: Not sure if this question is answerable but SE Economics seems like a much better fit.